# All but a finite number of finite simple groups are groups of matrices over $\mathbb{F}_q$

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups, representation-theory

In the introduction to this honors thesis, http://people.math.gatech.edu/~jrabinoff6/papers/building.pdf I found this statement:

> Matrix groups defined over the finite fields $\mathbb{F}_q$ comprise *all* finite simple groups except for the alternating group $A_n$ and a finite set of exceptions...

I found this statement very interesting.  I was wondering if anyone might know a reference, or be able to give an intuitive explanation of what is going on, as well as which groups do not show up and why.

Comment: This is a fantastically complicated theorem.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_simple_groups for an overview.  My (non-expert) understanding is that proving there are only finitely many exceptions is not all that much easier than proving the full classification.

Comment: There's also a brief comment to that extent [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_of_Lie_type#Relations_with_finite_simple_groups) on the Wikipedia page for groups of Lie type.

Comment: As pjs36 noted, these are not just "matrix groups", but finite groups of Lie type which appear in this classification. Just defining a finite group of Lie type is tricky, the first step is to define algebraic groups (groups of matrices defined by systems of polynomial equations over integers) and then specialize matrix entries to elements of finite fields.

Comment: As others have implied, in its current form, your statement is simply wrong. Every finite group is isomorphic to a group of matrices over any field - just take the regular representation. Also, for the groups of Lie type, it is usually not the matrix groups themselves that are simple: you have to factor out their centres (comprised of scalar matrices) first.